# Uploading images/files inside a PWA from PWABuilder

Tags: android, angular, file-upload, progressive-web-apps

I've build a PWA using PWABuilder from Microsoft, and created some webpages to show those within the PWA. On one of those pages the user should be able to upload images/files, within the browser it works fine, but inside my "app" nothing happens if the user clicks on "upload file".

Actually I am using Gravityforms for Wordpress to upload images, but since its not working I researched and found

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

but it isn't working neither.

Does anyone has an suggestion what else I could try?

Comment: By "app", do you mean clicking from a browser or a "native  app"

Comment: From "native app", from browser every thing is working perfect

Comment: But when i generate apk from PWABuilder the file upload button doesn't work